# Can I use Javascript to get a web page Without the use of XMLHttpRequest or document object?

Tags: javascript, html

web server send HTML(1) ---> Browser get the HTML(1) ---> script engine starts to work and so on..

I need to get a HTML(1) in my project.
'XMLHttpRequest.responseText' can do it. I think it's great!
But it have to make an another request.

And 'document.getElementsByTagName()' return a rendered HTML. It's not that I want.

we can see the HTML(1) in 'script' tab on IE developer tool.(not 'html' tab)
Then I guess that it could be possible to get HTML(1) without another request.

Is there any way to get the HTML(1) with javascript?

Added-----------------------------
there is sample.html

```
<script>
    document.write('AAAAAA');
</script>
<body>
body content
</body>
```

document.getElementsByTagName('html') return like following.

```
<script>
    document.write('AAAAAA');
</script>
<body>
AAAAAAbody content
</body>
```

But I need... pure source of the web page

Comment: Wait, do you want the source of the page you're currently looking at, or do you want the source of another page entirely?

Comment: exactly. source of the page I'm currently looking at.

Comment: Is there a reason you need the source in full from JavaScript and can't use something like `wget`? At least from poking around, it doesn't look like this is really possible. Are you building an extension?

Comment: @beanland I'm just designing some security model of web page. But it seems be impossible. :(  thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the current page as a string use `document.documentElement.innerHTML`

---

I don't think browsers actually keep the original HTML which was sent by web server, because if you try to view a page source the browser actually makes a request to the server.

Comment: It returned 'RENDERED' HTML. that's not that I want... I need HTML which was sent by web server.

Comment: I just updated my question. then you will know what I wanna ask.. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Musa, I think you're right. `document.documentElement.innerHTML` contained modified markup from that the server originally gave me.

Comment: Um.. Are you sure whenever we try to view a source, browser make a request to the server? Then whenever we open developer tool, it try to request to the server?

Comment: When you open developer tools it shows the dom tree built from the html and js manipulations, why would it have to send a request to the server to show that, also I checked(in chrome) before I posted that.

Comment: In Chrome, however, the Network developer tab will give you the source of the page without requiring a second load, which is I think where this confusion is coming from.

Comment: Only if it is open when the request is made.